# Html webpack plugin. Error: Child compilation failed:

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, node-modules, webpack-2

Html Webpack Plugin:
Error: Child compilation failed:
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ubuntu/pawntrust-ui/publ  ic/index.html':
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ubuntu/pawntrust-ui/publ  ic/index.html'

- compiler.js:79
  [pawntrust-ui]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16
- Compiler.js:343
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:343:11
- Compiler.js:681
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:681:15
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [pawntrust-ui]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compiler.js:678
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:678:31
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [pawntrust-ui]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compilation.js:1423
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [pawntrust-ui]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compilation.js:1414
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1414:32
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [pawntrust-ui]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compilation.js:1409
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1409:36
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [pawntrust-ui]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compilation.js:1405
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1405:32
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [pawntrust-ui]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compilation.js:1342 Compilation.seal
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1342:27
- Compiler.js:675
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:675:18
- Compilation.js:1261
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1261:4
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [pawntrust-ui]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compilation.js:1253 Compilation.finish
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1253:28
- Compiler.js:672
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:672:17
- Compilation.js:1185
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1185:12
- Compilation.js:1097
  [pawntrust-ui]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1097:9
- task_queues.js:79 processTicksAndRejections
  internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11

I tried by deleting node modules and installing them again. But nothing worked.Please help in solving this issue.

Comment: What does your webpack config look like? Most likely I believe you could have a mistake in spelling public with an accidental space in between the lowercase 'L' and 'i'. Atleast that's what your output seems to show I don't know if it matches your directory structure or not :D